# convert Html data into text using ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am getting data from a database, and in that data I have found some of the HTML tags in the form of a string, but when I display data to the frontend side I saw HTML tags are also. I want to convert that HTML tags data into there real value using ejs.

my code is -
fetch data -

```
app.get("/blogs/:id", (req, res) => {
  const requestParams = _.lowerCase(req.params.id);
  blogData.forEach(function (post) {
    const storedTitel = _.lowerCase(post.heading);
    if (storedTitel === requestParams) {
      res.render("blogsfullDetails", {
        date: post.date,
        heading: post.heading,
        subheading: post.subheading,
        discription: post.discription,
        discription2: post.discription2,
        image: post.image,
        image2: post.image2,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

ejs file -

```
<div class="blogTitle">
        <p class="date text-center"><%= date %></p>
        <p class="blog-heading text-center"><%= heading %></p>
        <p class="subText text-center"><%= subheading %></p>
        <div class="socialMedia">
          <a href="" target="_blank" ><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x" style="color: #0e76a8 ;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="" target="_blank" ><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" style="color: #fb3958;"></i></a>
          <a href="" target="_blank" ><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" style="color: #4267B2;"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-main-image" style="background-image: url('<%= image2 %>')"></div>
      <div class="blogText">
       <p><%= discription %></p>
        <div class="blog-main-image" style="background-image: url('<%= image %>')"></div>
      
       <p><%= discription2 %></p>
       
    </div>
```

frontend image -
[image]

I know how to convert Html data in text using dangerouslySetInnerHTML in React but don't know how to do it in ejs please help

Comment: I'm not sure what EJS or React have to do with this. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<%- html_variable ->`  syntax instead of `<%= variable >` , where rendering of raw HTML code is necessary.

UPD:
For the security proposes I'd recommend to parse html before using it directly.
Check out this tread: [What is "Escaped" & "Unescaped" output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727910/what-is-escaped-unescaped-output) and read about Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attack.

Comment: I got an error [ html_discription2 is not defined ]@ShevchenkoVV

Comment: You just have to left the discription2 there. I called my variable as *html_variable* just to say that it is different from *variable* property)

Comment: so where I can use html_ in my code @ShevchenkoVV

Comment: There is no special syntax called `html_`. 
You just need to replace the `<%= ... >` to `<%- ... >` syntax where you need to paste a raw HTML code to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

Install `npm i html-to-text` backend then

```
const {convert } = require('html-to-text')

app.get("/blogs/:id", (req, res) => {
  const requestParams = _.lowerCase(req.params.id);
  blogData.forEach(function (post) {
    const storedTitel = _.lowerCase(post.heading);
    if (storedTitel === requestParams) {
      res.render("blogsfullDetails", {
        date: post.date,
        heading: post.heading,
        subheading: post.subheading,
        discription: post.discription,
        discription2: post.discription2,
        image: post.image,
        image2: post.image2,
        convert : convert  
      });
    }
  });
});
```

then ejs file -

```
<div class="blogTitle">
        <p class="date text-center"><%= date %></p>
        <p class="blog-heading text-center"><%= heading %></p>
        <p class="subText text-center"><%= subheading %></p>
        <div class="socialMedia">
          <a href="" target="_blank" ><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x" style="color: #0e76a8 ;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="" target="_blank" ><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" style="color: #fb3958;"></i></a>
          <a href="" target="_blank" ><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" style="color: #4267B2;"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-main-image" style="background-image: url('<%= image2 %>')"></div>
      <div class="blogText">
       <p><%= convert(discription2) %></p>
        <div class="blog-main-image" style="background-image: url('<%= image %>')"></div>
      
       <p><%= convert(discription2) %></p>
       
    </div>
```